# Generar 'nonce' en WordPress con jQuery o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

¿Como género un nonce por jQuery o JavaScript?

Voy a enviar el siguiente ajax para que me cree un calendario de otro plugin al tiempo que el usuario llena algunos datos, el usuario no sabra que esto paso. Mi script es el siguiente:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#alisting-app > button').click(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery('#esb_subfield_title').focusout(function() {
                    var tag_name = jQuery('#esb_subfield_title').val();

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: 'https://www.midominio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            action: "add-tag",
                            screen: "edit-booked_custom_calendars",
                            taxonomy: "booked_custom_calendars",
                            post_type: "post",
                            "_wpnonce_add-tag": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                            _wp_http_referer: "/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=booked_custom_calendars",
                            "tag-name": tag_name
                        },
                        success: function(Data) {
                            console.log('Se creo el calendario');
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                            console.log('status: ' + jqXHR.status);
                            console.log('exception: ' + exception);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Al principio lo probe con nonce que me genero el plugin y me funciono, quise dejar el mismo nonce pero dejo de funcionar y si lo envio asi me retorna un error.

¿Como puedo generar este nonce?

Comment: En programación, `nonce` es la abreviatura de «number used once», es decir, funciona para un solo uso, por lo que debes generar uno nuevo cada que lo necesites. Revisa [esta página](https://ayudawp.com/nonces-wordpress/) para saber más.

Comment: dónde vas a insertar ese script?